# I am trying to learn LinkedList, I am a bit confused about adding element to the end

Tags: python, data-structures, linked-list

I am trying to add element at the end of Linked List.

When I do this, I get an attribute error *AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'next':*

```
def add_last(self, node_to_add):
    curr = self.head
    while curr is not None:
        curr = curr.next
    curr.next = Node(data = node_to_add)
```

But when I use `curr.next` to traverse, I am able to add the element at the end. Why do I get this error?

I have used `while curr is not None:` for removing nodes and it works.

Comment: `while curr is not None` should be `while curr.next is not None:`

Comment: You want to stop the loop when `curr` is the last element, so you can add the new element after it. You're going one step further, so `curr` is the `None` after the last element.

Comment: Note also that you need a special case to handle the list being empty, e.g. `if self.head == None: self.head = Node(data = node_to_add)` (assuming you don't use dummy nodes).

Comment: In your own words, if you have a loop that says `while curr is not None:`, and you allow this loop to keep running until the condition is not met, what do you think should be the value of `curr` after the loop? Why? (Hint: there is an easy way that you can reason about this, without having to think about each time that the loop runs separately.) Do you see why this would cause a problem?

Comment: (Hint: did you already write a method to *find* the last node in the list? Does it work? What if you try *using that* to implement this logic?)

Answer (score 0):

A good way to understand how errors unfold in situations like this is to literally draw your data structures out on a piece of paper with a pencil, and trace the behavior- where things are pointing, what current values are of each variable, and how they change. Consider what happens here.

1. `curr` is assigned to `self.head`
2. A `while` loop is encountered. The first thing that happens is that the loop condition `curr is not None` is tested. Here there could be two outcomes:

   - 2A: `curr` *is* `None` (`self.head` was `None`), in which case the `while` loop is skipped, and the next line is run. The next line happens to be `curr.next = Node(data = node_to_add)` which is trying to obtain the `next` property from `curr`, but this fails because `curr` is set to `None`! There *is* no "none" property of `None`.
   - 2B: `curr` is *not* `None`. In this case, the `while` loop is entered. `curr = curr.next` is executed. This whole step is then repeated. Eventually, the end of the linked list is reached, and the while loop exits. Except, the only way the loop can exit is once `curr` is `None`. And once `curr` *is* set to `None`-- that is, it isn't set to any object at all anymore, there is no object there from which to get the "next" property, so again, just like in situation 2A above, an error occurs.

So this code is guaranteed to end in an error, because it always traverses *past* the end of the linked list, and then immediately tries to manipulate the properties of the (non-existent) object there, as if it were still pointing to a valid object at that point.